# Populate Javascript var with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I need a solution for my simple js api.

I want to send the IP of the visitor on the same pageload when i populate the IP var with PHP.

```
<script>var ipadress=<?='"' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '";'?></script>
```

and de api file below needs this IP adres for a XMLHttpRequest on the same pageload without refreshing.

```
<script src="//mysite.com/js/api.js" defer></script>
```

Is this possible? PHP REMOTE_ADDR is server side en de js api is client side. Any suggestions? Or some work arround??

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes! No IP send on the first pageload